# Using AspectJ Without Spring on Maven

Tags: java, spring, maven, aspectj, aspectj-maven-plugin

I am still beginner in Java. I would like to build a simple Maven project and implement AspectJ to monitor some stuffs. I followed this [tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/aspectj_based_aop_appoach.htm) and this [tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/spring3/spring-aop-aspectj-annotation-example/)but it all points to use Spring in the Maven, which will complicate some stuffs in the project. Do you have any suggestions for workaround that? I already put AspectJ Maven plugin in the pom.xml but it doesn't work.

Thanks

ps. These are the example codes I would like to get.

MainApp.java

```
package tester;

public class MainApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        HelloWorld a = new HelloWorld();
        a.printHello();
    }
}
```

HelloWorld.java

```
package tester;

public class HelloWorld {
    private String name;

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void printHello() {
        System.out.println("Spring 3 : Hello ! " + name);
    }}
```

TestAspect.java

```
package tester;

import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.After;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.AfterThrowing;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.AfterReturning;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;


@Aspect
public class TestAspect {

//  @Pointcut("execution(* /HelloSpring/src/main/java/tester/HelloWorld.setName(..))")
//  private void testing(){
//      
//  }

    @Before("execution(* tester.HelloWorld.printHello(..))")
    public void testBefore2(){
        System.out.println("yoo2");
    }


    @Before("execution(* tester.HelloWorld.setName(String))")
    public void testBefore(){
        System.out.println("yoo");
    }

}
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>test.spring</groupId>
  <artifactId>HelloSpring</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <properties>
  <spring.version>4.2.5.RELEASE</spring.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>

        <!-- Spring 3 dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.8</version>
        </dependency>
  </dependencies>


  <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.8</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
                        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.compiler.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a better suited pom, for me it works with the current code.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>test.spring</groupId>
<artifactId>HelloSpring</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

<properties>
    <maven.compiler.plugin.version>3.5.1</maven.compiler.plugin.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.8</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>


<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
            <configuration>
                <complianceLevel>1.8</complianceLevel>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven.compiler.plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: I tried using your POM configuration but it still does not work. Do you have any idea why? Do you think I need to convert the normal Maven project to Maven AspectJ project using Right Click - Configure - Convert to AspectJ Project?

Comment: What IDE are you using? Have you tried running it via console just with mvn clean install? Im using IntelliJ and i have tried both from console and from IntelliJ and i can run your code with my POM.

Comment: I am using Eclipse Mars and haven't tried from console as it has some problems with it. But I already tried to build it with clean install arguments still AspectJ is not captured.

Answer (score 1):

You should add "execution" tag as well:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${aspectj-maven-plugin.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <complianceLevel>1.8</complianceLevel>
        <source>1.8</source>
        <target>1.8</target>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
         <execution>
             <phase>process-sources</phase>
             <goals>
                 <goal>compile</goal>
                 <goal>test-compile</goal>
             </goals>
         </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${maven.compiler.plugin.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.8</source>
        <target>1.8</target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```